# Touch Screen Ripple Effect In JQuery for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, click, touch, screen, ripple

I have a touch screen tablet. Now if I was a Windows user I could use [iTouch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GLymNwgKgM), but I'm a Linux user, and what about OS 10, or the users that got the Chromebook, or installed Chromium OS on their tablet pc?

Well I thought of exactly that, and well I found [this](http://www.fluidbyte.net/clickecho-jquery-plugin) site, and the user created the ripple effect.

However how to make this as a chrome extension so the ripple effect is shown every time the user clicks, with a background radial gradient done in CSS3 representing the content of whatever website the user maybe on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major component of such extension would be injecting this js library into all pages along with css. You can do this with so called [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html).

Then you would need some way of turning it on/off. It is usually done with a [browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/browserAction.html) (toolbar button) or context menu.

A good way to start would be reading through those links (and everythign else on that site).

**UPDATE**

It doesn't work because in your background page when you are calling:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "js/ripple.js"});
```

It is getting injected right away into a tab that was current during extension installation (which is most likely `chrome://extensions/`, where you can't inject anything).

That's why I mentioned earlier that for triggering the effect you would most likely want to user browser action button. Your background page should look like:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "js/ripple.js"});
});
```

Or if you want this ripple effect to be always on, just add `ripple.js` to the manifestwith the rest of the scripts.

Comment: I updated the topic. Can't seem to figure out why the extension's not working.